# Haskell- Type matching

Tags: haskell, types, matching

I having trouble getting the output from a helper function to match my output of the function I am using the code below:

```
getSemiDiag :: [[Maybe Player]] -> Int -> Int -> [Maybe Player]
getSemiDiag [] _ _ = []
getSemiDiag (x:xs) start size = if start > (size -1)
                            then []
                            else (x !! start) : (getSemiDiag xs (start+1) size)



semiRight :: [[Maybe Player]] -> Int -> Int -> [[Maybe Player]]
semiRight [] _ _ = []
semiRight (x:xs) start size = if start > (size -1)
                          then []
                          else (getSemiDiag x start size) : (semiRight xs (start+1) size)
```

the function semiRight won't match up despite my best efforts. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but you're passing a `[Maybe Player]` to `getSemiDiag` where that expects a `[[Maybe Player]]`. Did you mean to have `getSemiDiag (x:xs) start size : semiRight xs (start+1) size`?

Comment: `then []` should probably be `then [[]]`

Answer (score 1):

Judging only from the type, `x` is matched to a element which has a type of `[Maybe Player]`,

you should obviously pass [x] but not x to getSemiDiag.
Moreover, some brackets are redundant.

```
semiRight :: [[Maybe Player]] -> Int -> Int -> [[Maybe Player]]
semiRight [] _ _ = []
semiRight (x:xs) start size = if start > (size -1)
                          then []
                          else getSemiDiag [x] start size : semiRight xs (start+1) size
```

Why not just use zipWith

```
semiRight players start size = zipWith (\p i -> [p !! i]) players [start .. size]
```